# JSON Accessing and Searching Nested Object with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to access nested JSON, for example

```
var SchoolData =  {
        "SchoolRecord": {
            "classX": {
                "name": "Student Name 1",
                "subject": {
                    "mathsDept": {
                        "subject": "Maths",
                        "marks": 87
                    },
                    "scienceDept": {
                        "subject": "Physics",
                        "marks": 55                
                    },
                    "socialDept": {
                        "subject": "Social",
                        "marks": 95
                    }
                }
            },
            "classIX": {
                "name": "Student Name 2",
                 "subject": {
                    "mathsDept": {
                        "subject": "Maths",
                        "marks": 99
                    },
                    "scienceDept": {
                        "subject": "Physics",
                        "marks": 95

                    },
                    "socialDept": {
                        "subject": "Social",
                        "marks": 91
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    console.log(SchoolData.SchoolRecord);

console.log(SchoolData.SchoolRecord[0]);
```

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mvxkpttg/1/).

I want marks in JSON data `SchoolData.marks`

Comment: `SchoolData.SchoolRecord.classX.subject.mathsDept.marks`

Comment: You have to traverse down each property

Comment: i dont want to access by object, i want classX and classIX records in one statement

Comment: You've told us what the input is, now show us what the desired output should look like and explain the logic for getting from one to the other.

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd `console.log` fails because you're treating `SchoolData.SchoolRecord` as an array when it's an object.

To get at all the marks you'll need to drill down into each class object:

```
console.log(SchoolData.SchoolRecord.classX.subject.mathsDept);
console.log(SchoolData.SchoolRecord.classX.subject.scienceDept);
console.log(SchoolData.SchoolRecord.classX.subject.socialDept);
console.log(SchoolData.SchoolRecord.classIX.subject.mathsDept);
console.log(SchoolData.SchoolRecord.classIX.subject.scienceDept);
console.log(SchoolData.SchoolRecord.classIX.subject.socialDept);
```

This isn't ideal but it might suit your needs.

If you have any control over the format of that data, think about structuring with arrays. Maybe something like:

```
var schoolData = {
    schoolRecord: {
        classes: [
            {name: "classX", student: {name: "Student Name 1", subjects: [
                {dept: "Maths", subject: "Maths", marks: [99]}
                {dept: "Physics", subject: "Physics", marks: [99]}
            ]}}
        ]
    }
}
```

Which is a complete guess as I don't know your data structure. The use of arrays will mean extracting data "should" be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Use this following line of code.

```
SchoolData.SchoolRecord.classX.subject.mathsDept.marks
```

For fetching data with index -

```
SchoolData.SchoolRecord[0]
```

You have to create an array of records

```
var SchoolData =  {
        "SchoolRecord": [{
            "classX": {
                "name": "Student Name 1",
                "subject": {
                    "mathsDept": {
                        "subject": "Maths",
                        "marks": 87
                    },
                    "scienceDept": {
                        "subject": "Physics",
                        "marks": 55                
                    },
                    "socialDept": {
                        "subject": "Social",
                        "marks": 95
                    }
                }
            },
            "classIX": {
                "name": "Student Name 2",
                 "subject": {
                    "mathsDept": {
                        "subject": "Maths",
                        "marks": 99
                    },
                    "scienceDept": {
                        "subject": "Physics",
                        "marks": 95

                    },
                    "socialDept": {
                        "subject": "Social",
                        "marks": 91
                    }
                }
            }
        }]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very easily with the [_.each() function in underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/).

Here is the solution in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g87g28h5/1/

The essential bit is here:

```
for(var Class in SchoolData.SchoolRecord) {
    _.each(SchoolData.SchoolRecord[Class].subject, function(item) {
        var entry = "<li>" + Class;
        entry += ": " + item.subject;
        entry += " = " + item.marks;
        entry += "</li>";
        listing.innerHTML = listing.innerHTML + entry;
    });
}
```